# I can't see Android SDK javadoc in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing for Android in Eclipse Helios. I'm using the latest ADT plugin 8.0.1. Previously, I could see method javadoc description, when moving my mouse over a method name and waiting for about a second. Now it stopped working for some reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. In eclipse, right click on your Android project and select Properties
2. On the menu on the left, select "Java Build Path"
3. On the right hand side, select the "tab" labelled "Libraries".
4. Here you should see the Android SDK that you're targeting. For example: "Android 2.2".
5. Click on the arrow to the left of the Android SDK to expand the sublevels.
6. Find "Android.jar" and click on the arrow to the left of that one as well to expand it.
7. You'll see a setting called "Javadoc location". Select that and then click on the "Edit" button.
8. At the top, RESELECT the path to your javadocs. This is usually "path_to_android_sdk/android-sdk-mac_86/docs/reference/". I say RESELECT because even if it's right, you should browse and do it over anyway.
9. Click on "validate". You should be all set now!

As it is told in this article http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2011/02/losing-javadocs-in-eclipse-solution.html Thanks to Chris

For some reason it is adding an static windows OS path starting with D:\...
This also correct all SDK targets.

Comment: For this to work for me I had to first install the "Documentation for Android SDK" which wasn't already install.  Once that was done I was able to perform the steps listed in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Helios is known to have slow code completion with the Android SDK. Perhaps your problems are related to that? If you have problems with the latest Eclipse version, you should probably try using **Eclipse 3.5 http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/**, which doesn't have these issues.

This could be due to some sort of temporary error in Eclipse.

You can check **Window -> Show View (-> General ) -> Error Log** to check whether there has been an Eclipse exception which has caused the Eclipse designer to bail out.

Have you tried to restart Eclipse? If it still doesn't work you can try to restart eclipse with

c:\path\to\eclipse.exe -clean

You can also check the Windows-Preferences and Project->Properties if you can find anything related to Javadoc there and try to reset the java perspective using Window -> Reset perspective.