# Javadoc not displayed on some Android methods in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

I just updated Eclipse and the Android mods in Eclipse to v14. I restarted Eclipse and checked for updates again (Help->Check for Updates && via Android SDK Manager) and there were none. Now I have a problem with Javadoc where some methods that I know have javadocs are not showing up and result in this message "The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc". Two are the Intent constructor and the putParcelableArrayListExtra methods. The javadoc for the Intent class is available, but not the constructor.. Includes are fine, I can compile the app OK.

I know the Javadocs are there. I can drill into them with a web browser from the doc/references directory.

I have searched the Google and stack overflow and found [references to reselect the javadoc location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728733/i-cant-see-android-sdk-javadoc-in-eclipse)!, which I have done to no avail.

I also uninstalled the Documentation package and reinstalled it (and restarted Eclipse).

Any tips?